# While loop inside SELECT

Tags: php, html, forms, select, while-loop

I am new to php and html, so I need some help with a problem: I am trying to make a form where you can select from a dropbox, but thae data from the dropbox should be retrieved from a sql database.
If I save the code bellow as php, the dropbox is created and retrieves the data from sql, but then the submit button (together with everything else I put after the while loop) disappeares. If I save it as a html file, the form and submit button works, but it doesn't retrieve any data from sql database.

Thanks

```
<form action="Techniques.php" method="post">
        <p>Which Disease?
        <select name="disease" >
            <option value="" >--Select--</option>
        <?php
          require_once("dbconnect.php");

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM diseases";
          $result = mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error());
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error()))
                {
        ?>
                 <option value ="<?php echo($row['Disease']);?>"><?php echo($row['Disease']);?></option>
        <?php
                }
        ?>        

        </select>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Copmlete"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: "<" ?? missing in -->  input type="submit" value="Copmlete"/>

Comment: `Copmlete` -> `Complete`?

Comment: Not quite answering your question, but I prefer to do all my database-querying **before** I ever get to the HTML output part of the page. This gives you more flexibility in how you want to handle database errors. Once you've sent any HTML content, you can't take it back. (Recovering from an error while you're inside a `<select>` is practically impossible.) In the short-term, however, you could always try [output buffers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) so you didn't have to re-arrange all your code.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do it differnt in the future. But I just started learning php and sql by myself last week. So I am still just trying out and don't know yet how I should do it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save your file as a .html file, the PHP code won't be executed.

The .html extension you see in many websites on files that contain PHP is obtained through URL rewriting.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
So I will save it as php.file, but the output still stops after the while loop.
Anything I add after the while loop doesn't show up in the output? So the submit button doesn't appear if I save as php, but it appears if I save as html.

Comment: I noticed that you wrote `<?php echo($row['Disease']);?>` echo doesn't need () so it would be `<?php echo $row['Disease'];?>` you're probably getting a parse error, hence the output stopping.

Also don't use `or die(mysql_error())` in the while loop.

Comment: Now it works! It was the or die(mysql_error() that caused the error.

Answer (score 2):

your

```
    </select>
  </p>
  input type="submit" value="Copmlete"/>
</form>
```

must be

```
    </select>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Complete"/>
</form>
```

Best Coding:

```
<?php
   require_once("dbconnect.php");
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM diseases";
   $result = mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error());
?>
<form action="Techniques.php" method="post">
  <p>Which Disease?
    <select name="disease" >
      <option value="" >--Select--</option>
      <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error()))
        {
      ECHO "<option value='disease'>$row['Disease']</option>"
        }
      ?>        
    </select>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Copmlete"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Edit 2 is missing a closing `?>` before starting the `<form>`.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
<form action="Techniques.php" method="post">
  <p>Which Disease?
    <select name="disease" >
      <option value="" >--Select--</option>
      <?php
        require_once("dbconnect.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM diseases";
        $result = mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error());
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error()))
          {
      ?>
        <option value="<?php echo($row['Disease']);?>" ><?php echo($row['Disease']);?></option>

      <?php } ?>        

      </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Complete"/>
</form>
```